# Wicket retrieve page url parameters

Tags: url, iframe, parameters, wicket, html

I have two Wicket applications. They are started seperately. Now I want to open let's say application B in an iFrame of application A. Now I encounter a problem because I need to retrieve the extra parameters that are in the URL.

Example:

Application A runs on localhost:4321
Application B runs on localhost:1234

Application A contains an IFrame and opens Application B in this iframe with the following url:
src="localhost:1234/PageParameter=400"

Now I want to retrieve the PageParameter=400 part of the url in application B.

I tried to retrieve the parameters using:

```
Url url = ((WebRequest)RequestCycle.get().getRequest()).getUrl();
String fullUrl = RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl(url);
```

But I do not know how to retrieve the parameters when the page is called by application A.

**UPDATE**:
If you are struggling with accepting dynamic urls on your Wicket page. Take a look at this post: People who are struggeling with accepts dynamic urls take a look at this post: http://vozis.blogspot.nl/2012/01/wicket-mountpage-with-optional.html I used it to accept the url and dynamic amount of parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a constructor for a page, that takes PageParameters as it's argument. It would look something like that:

```
class MyPage extends WebPage {
   public MyPage(PageParameters parameters) {
      String p = parameters.get("PageParameter").toString(); //p == "400"
   }
}
```

It's assuming that the page is correctly mounted, but if you are accessing it from outside it should be.